# How can I detect the change of value in a QInputDialog?

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, qinputdialog

I want to print the value when changing the value of the dialog called by the `getInt` method of `QInputDialog`.

I run the below code, but it is not working:

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtCore import Slot
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QInputDialog

@Slot(int)
def int_value_changed(val):
    print(val)

if 'qapp' not in globals():
    qapp = QApplication(sys.argv)

dlg = QInputDialog(None)
dlg.intValueChanged.connect(int_value_changed)

dlg.getInt(None, 'title', 'Type Value', 0)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Functions like `getInt` are static, which means they create an internal instance of `QInputDialog` which is not directly accessible from code. If you create your own instance of `QInputDialog`, you must do all the initialisation yourself and then call `exec()` (just like an ordinary dialog). As the documentation for [QInputDialog](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qinputdialog.html) shows, this approach is more flexible than using the static functions, since it provides much more scope for customisation.

A roughly equivalent implementation of `getInt` would be:

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QInputDialog

def int_value_changed(val):
    print(val)

if QApplication.instance() is None:
    qapp = QApplication(sys.argv)

def getInt(parent, title, label, value=0):
    dlg = QInputDialog(parent)
    dlg.setInputMode(QInputDialog.IntInput)
    dlg.setWindowTitle(title)
    dlg.setLabelText(label)
    dlg.setIntValue(value)
    dlg.intValueChanged.connect(int_value_changed)
    accepted = dlg.exec_() == QInputDialog.Accepted
    dlg.deleteLater()
    return dlg.intValue(), accepted

print(getInt(None, 'Title', 'Type Value', 5))

# print(QInputDialog.getInt(None, 'title', 'Type Value', 5))
```